# Python subprocess module

Tags: python, subprocess, command-prompt, popen, prompt

I am making a GUI aplplication in Python that requires to run a `cmd` prompt command.

e. g.:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("arp -a > arptable.txt",stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE,shell=Ture)
```

Now, after running this command, I see a small splash of `cmd screen`, and a text file containing the `arp` table is generated. In my application, I don't want this black screen to splash, so that the user doesn't know there's a `cmd prompt` involved in the appplication.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `shell=True`:

```
import os
from subprocess import PIPE, STDOUT, check_call

with open("arptable.txt", "rb") as file, open(os.devnull, "r+b") as devnull:
    check_call(["arp", "-a"], stdin=devnull, stdout=file, stderr=STDOUT)
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you need to pass a [`STARTUPINFO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#windows-popen-helpers) class to the `startupinfo` argument of [`subprocess.Popen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) to make that happen. To make that portable:

```
import subprocess
import os

si = None
if os.name == 'nt':
    si = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    si.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
proc = subprocess.Popen("arp -a > arptable.txt",stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, startupinfo=si)
```